# Extract stuff from text using Regex and Java

Tags: java, regex, string, text

I have some text like this:

```
 //(10,0,'Computer_accessibility','',''),(13,0,'History_of_Afghanistan','',''),(14,0,'Geography_of_Afghanistan','','')
```

and I wrote a pattern:

```
public final static Pattern r_english = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)\\)");
```

This works well in Java to extract m.group(1) (e.g. 13) and m.group(3) (e.g. History_of_Afghanistan) where m is a matcher.
However, it breaks if the text is like this, since Washington,_D.C. (ie. m.group(3)) has a comma in it:

```
(8543,0,'Washington,_D.C.','',''),(8546,0,'Extermination_camp','','')
```

Can someone help me in with the regex to modify it and extract the Washington,_D.C. thingy? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Change your third capture group to capture everything until a closing `'` is reached. That allows every character (including your comma) to be captured.

UPDATE: to allow escaped `'`s as well, the regex looks like this. Credits go to Pshemo, see the comments.

```
public final static Pattern r_english = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?),(.*?),('(?:[^']|\\')*'),(.*?),(.*?)\\)");
```

Comment: Now I am waiting for info from OP that title may also have more than `'` in it. But for now this looks OK.

Comment: So far it's not in the example input :D

Comment: BTW, you probably don't need that `?` in `'[^']*?'`. Also `(.*?)` can be changed into `([^,]*)`.

Comment: @Pshemo you are correct, it's useless. I removed it.

Comment: @Pshemo: you're right, I should've been careful while posting, the third group might have ' like: Marvin's_Room_(play)

Comment: @Knight In that case you need to create some format which will allow us to determine which `'` is part of title, and which `'` is considered as quote representing end of title. In other words you need to introduce some escaping mechanism of that non-special `'` like preceding it with ``\`` (but this would also mean that ``\`` is special so just like in String literals you would need to also escape it if you would want to create such symbol), or like SQL does, escape each textual `'` it with another `'` like `'Marvin''s_Room'`.

Comment: Absolutely, I just noticed after a lot of grep-ping that they specify the quotes using a slash (just like you said) like so: (32532831,0,'I_Don\'t_Blame_You_at_All','','')

Comment: @Knight In that case instead of `[^']` which accept only non-quote characters, try to write accept non-quotes OR escaped quote. So try to change `('[^']*')` into something like `('(?:[^']|\\')*')` <- you need to write ``\\`` as ``\\\\`` in String literal. If you are wondering what `(?:...)` is, it is called non-capturing group, it is a group which is not included in group tree, so you can't access it via `group(index)`, I did it to not affect your current group indexes.

Comment: @Knight Oh, lets not forget that this regex will not strip your text from these escaping metacharacters (particularly ``\``), so your title will still be in form `I_Don\'t_Blame_You_at_All` instead of `I_Don't_Blame_You_at_All`. So you will need to add layer which will un-escape such string to proper text. But to be honest this looks like reinventing the wheel. If it is possible you should stop using this `(data, data), (data, data)` format, and move to standard ones like JSON, CVS, or XML which parser already have these problems solved.

Comment: The regex outputs: group 1: 10 group 3: 'Computer_accessibility','',''),(13,0,'History_of_Afghanistan','',''),(14,0,'Geography_of_Afghanistan','',''),(8543,0,'Washington,_D.C.','',''),(32532831,0,'I_Don't_Blame_You_at_All'

 for the input: String data = "(10,0,'Computer_accessibility','',''),(13,0,'History_of_Afghanistan','',''),(14,0,'Geography_of_Afghanistan','',''),"
        + "(8543,0,'Washington,_D.C.','',''),(32532831,0,'I_Don\'t_Blame_You_at_All','','')"; 

and as I use "System.out.print("group 1: " + m.group(1));
      System.out.print(" group 3: " + m.group(3)); " to print out.

Answer (score 1):

You should help to make your RegEx more specific to your case.
For example:

```
((.*?),(.*?),('.*?'),('.*?'),('.*?'))
```

I used the parantehesis `'`, this solution is also agnostic to further parantehesis in Group 3-5.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your regular expression in order to fit all the matchings that you want to retrieve, E.g.:

```
/((.*?),(.*?),'(.*?)','(.*?)','(.*?)'\)/g
```

Working Example @ [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mIUc3L/1)

You need to translate/escape the above regular expression into a Java compatible one, E.g.:

```
public static String REGEX_PATTERN = "\\((.*?),(.*?),'(.*?)','(.*?)','(.*?)'\\)";
```

Then, iterate through all the matchings trying to mimic the `//g` modifier, E.g.:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
}
```

Java Working Example:

```
package SO40002225;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static String INPUT;
    public static String REGEX_PATTERN;

    static {
        INPUT = "(8543,0,'Washington,_D.C.','',''),(8546,0,'Extermination_camp','',''),(8543,0,'Washington,_D.C.','',''),(8546,0,'Extermination_camp','','')";
        REGEX_PATTERN = "\\((.*?),(.*?),'(.*?)','(.*?)','(.*?)'\\)";
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = INPUT;

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String mg1 = matcher.group(1);
            String mg2 = matcher.group(2);
            String mg3 = matcher.group(3);
            String mg4 = matcher.group(4);
            String mg5 = matcher.group(5);

            System.out.println("Matching group #1: " + mg1);
            System.out.println("Matching group #2: " + mg2);
            System.out.println("Matching group #3: " + mg3);
            System.out.println("Matching group #4: " + mg4);
            System.out.println("Matching group #5: " + mg5);
        }

    }

}
```

### Update #1

Removed the escape done for commas `,` with-in the regular expression, as pointed by Pshemo, the `,` is not a meta-character or it's not being used within a **limit repetition** quantifier: `{min, max}`

Comment: Sorry, but what is the point of escaping `,`? It is not one of regex metacharacters (at least not here - only case where `,` doesn't represent literal is inside quantifiers like `{min,max}` or `{,max}` but even then there is also no point in escaping it).

Comment: @Pshemo, Thank you for pointing this out, I completely forgot about this.